# How can I see mobile version websites on PC/Mac while using a privacy secure browser such as Tor

Tags: web-browser, tor

Tor doesn't recommend downloading plugins to enable mobile site viewing... So is there any other "secure" browser that'll let me see mobile sites securely?

Comment: Question regarding product recommendations are [off-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: define 'securely'

Answer (score 1):

Change user agent in Tor Browser to mobile device.

Open browser, type:

> about:config

find

> general.useragent.override

and replace it with mobile user agent, an example:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; ; ) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Mobile Safari/

To see effect, try to visit any site:
[image]